# sikuli type and paste return wrong result

Tags: types, paste, sikuli

```
paste(Pattern("openfiledialog.png").targetOffset(-140,1), 
'C:\sikuliTests\ITEstandAlone.sikuli\ITEtest\122L_InputModel.STL')
```

returns:

```
C:\sikuliTests\ITEstandAlone.sikuli\ITEtestRL_InputModel.STL
```

type instead of paste does the same. The pattern is standard edit field in the open file dialog.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking and what your problem is exactly. Are you trying to paste a text and a different text is being pasted?

Comment: exactly: instead of "ITEtest\122L_InputModel.STL" it inserts "ITEtestRL_InputModel.STL"
as result - "file not found"

Comment: Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your case here is that Sikuli reads the `\122` as `R` according to the ascii encoding and hence you get `R` in your resulting string. This can be easily fixed by adding "escape character" before `\122`:

```
C:\sikuliTests\ITEstandAlone.sikuli\ITEtest\\122L_InputModel.STL
```

Comment: @pavelageyev please accept the answer if that solved your problem